# Google Waves - basic structure

Tags: google-wave

Is a wave limited to the sharing of textual information (HTML), or am I correct in assuming that a wave can contain arbitrary data (represented in XML), so long as it also contains the javascript necessary to render it in a meaningful way?

I ask because the collaborative document preparation demonstrated in the Google I/O video looks very powerful, but there are many other types of documents than simple rtf text.  In my case I would be looking interactively to develop gantt charts.

Comment: Has Google released any info on this other than allowing those present at the conference access to the beta?

Answer (score 3):

I got access to Google Wave a few days ago, and here's what the raw data for their [Sokoban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) game (which supports two players playing simultaneously on the same board) looks like, for example:

```
<blip>
  <p _t="title">
  </p>
  <p>
    <w:gadget author="blixt@wavesandbox.com" prefs="" state="" title="" url="http://sokoban-server.appspot.com/com.example.simplegadget.client.SokobanGadget.gadget.xml">
      <w:pref name="playerAllocation" value="1 1,blixt">
      </w:pref>
      <w:pref name="totalMoves" value="8">
      </w:pref>
      <w:pref name="playerPositions" value="1 4,2">
      </w:pref>
      <w:pref name="rockPositions" value="6 2,2 3,2 14,2 15,2 16,2 4,3">
      </w:pref>
    </w:gadget>
  </p>
</blip>
```

So yes, you can store any data you like in a single blip, with the possibility to go backwards in "time" to see older versions of the data etc.

---

By the way, if you're interested in seeing some code for a robot that sits in a wave and interacts with users, I made one for a game I'm developing: [Google Code Project for multifarce](http://code.google.com/p/multifarce) (and [the game in question](http://multifarce.appspot.com/), it's not really public yet and as such not particularly functional.) The bot source is here: [multifarce Wave robot source](http://code.google.com/p/multifarce/source/browse/app/wave.py)

Basically, all you need to get a bot running are the 14 last lines in that code. I love it! `=)`

Comment: Awesome. I can't wait to see the finished product!

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot that can be done inside each Wave. They have not yet made all features available, but here is a link to some samples: http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/ which includes my Slashdot Gadget:http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=18006
The Slashdot Gadget actually takes the RSS feed for Slashdot and displays the latest headlines.
Here is the XML: http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/slashdot.xml
[alt text http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/xml.jpg](http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/xml.jpg)